# Password-Reset / Parse-Server

Tags: heroku, mailgun, parse-server, password-recovery

I just moved an app from Parse.com to Parse-Server.
It has users and I have an issue to send password-reset mails.
I am getting this message:

[image]

I read on the net that I need to change index.js.
But I have no index.js at this point.
So what do I need to do to make the password-reset mails work?
I already have an account on MailGun, which is needed as far as I have read, to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in order to support Password reset you need to define an email adapter inside your index.js file. 
index.js file is located under the root folder of your parse-server project. the index.js is the file where ParseServer is being initialized. 
The email adapters which are currently supported by parse-server are [sendgrid](https://github.com/oursky/parse-server-sendgrid-adapter) and [mailgun](https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-mailgun)

Adding email adapter is pretty simple:

1. Install the relevant email adapter module. Enter **npm install {email_module_name} --save** in your parse-server project folder
2. Open **index.js** file and go to where ParseServer is being initalized and add the property **verifyUserEmails: true**
3. Add **emailAdapter** also the where ParseServer is being initialized

```js
    emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: {
          // The address that your emails come from
          fromAddress: 'parse@example.com',
          // Your domain from mailgun.com
          domain: 'example.com',
          // Your API key from mailgun.com
          apiKey: 'key-mykey',
        }
```

Comment: I'm kind of lost here. For this app my local root folder is empty. The (iOS) app works and there is a DB on mLab. Should I create an index.js from scratch?

Comment: No, you just need to make sure that you provide all the parameters and that the email adapter that you put is working .

Comment: Yes I understand that, but since I have not index.js yet. Do I create one? How? I have started only recently to use Heroku and Node.js. And even what I have made working I only understand about half.

Comment: Yes you need. In the index.js you need to create the ParseServer instance and there to put your email adapter, public URL and all other configurations.

Comment: I had left alone this issue for a while in order to deal with some other heroku/node.js problems. But it's now time for me to come back to this one.
I now have the code you mention in my ParseServer initialization code. But I still get the same message.
I have run "npm install mailgun.js" and added "var mailgun = require('mailgun.js');" to my index.js. But I must be missing some important point on the way.

Comment: You need to install mailgun parse server module not the mailgun SDK module.. (checkout this one: https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-mailgun)

Comment: Isn't this what "npm install mailgun.js" does? Anyway, after I added "verifyUserEmails: true;" and "appName: 'Parse App'"; it finally worked.
I am happy that it now works. I am not so happy that I only understand about 50% of the whole thing. Thank you for your help anyhow.